# Enclose article's body with default shortcode

Tags: shortcode, templates

I'd like to enable this plugin https://responsivevoice.com/wordpress-text-to-speech-plugin/ as default for every article's body in my wordpress site.

I need to edit my article template and the final result should be

```
[responsivevoice voice="UK English Female" buttontext="Listen to this"] The body article [/responsivevoice]
```

Do you have some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try their support? Plugin specific questions are usually off topic here. As for this plugin, I don't know enough about it to properly help you

Comment: It's not a specific plugin question, I'd like only to know how to enclose the body of article with a custom shortcode...

Comment: Ah, I see. You can check, but most themes use `the_content()` / [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) to display article content. You can [apply a filter to add your shortcode](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wordpress%20using%20filters), you might need to use an additional [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kero I have implemented this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[responsivevoice voice="Italian Female" buttontext="Ascolta"]'.'<br>'.$bodyContent.'[/responsivevoice]'); ?>
```

The $bodyContent variable contains the HTML value of the article's body, obtained using this function: http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/08/31/get_the_content-with-formatting/index.html

```
<?php $bodyContent = get_the_content_with_formatting(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, just using the shortcode `[responsivevoice_button]` will add a button that speaks all the content. You shouldn't need to wrap it with a shortcode.

Their example (emphasis mine):

> Add this shortcode to your page or post to speak the **entire page**
>
> ```
> [responsivevoice_button voice="UK English Female" buttontext="Listen to Post"]
> ```

Comment: But I don't want to speak the entire page, as I wrote in the first post I want to speak only the body!

Comment: It does only read the body. I can see from the code of the plugin that `[responsivevoice_button]` only reads the value of `get_the_content()`.

Comment: I tried but their documentation is wrong, if I add only the shortcode it produces an empty text.

Comment: It’s not the documentation, I’m looking at the actual plugin code! Did you notice that it’s a different shortcode?